# Change <body> to <body id"something" runat="server'>

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a huge website with main.master that is used in a lot of places.. If I change the  tag to runat="server", would any other regular stuff continue working or it would not get affected if I change it?

Thank you

Comment: Ok I am confused. So it seems like javascript wont work?, there are a bunch of javascript folders in this website so i guess is better not to risk it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything will continue to work.  You will then also be able to affect the  tag in code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add runat="server" to the body tag.  Be sure to define the ID clearly, and you may need to reference it yourself within your code since it's an HTML element not an ASP.NET control

Answer (score 0):

only javascript wont work if you put runat="server", when I say javascript i mean on those method that search for body by id, because when you add runat="server" your id won't be "something" it will be autogenerated string which is showing path to your body. for example ctl0_master_something. but before you do it just add "=" before your id"something" (id="something")

Comment: But can't you compensate for that in your javascript by replacing the reference to body with a reference to body.clientID?

Comment: simple search and replace will do it, but I just mention that as a example if he is trying to find body by id it won't be possible cause id will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The javascripts and css references may fail to work depending on your referencing pattern. At places with runat tag the reference using ~ sign will work fine.
At places where you do not use runat="server" then use this kind of referencing and it should work fine:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/style.css") %>' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js") %>"></script>
```